# How to concatenate an hex to a string in C

Tags: c, winapi, tchar

I'm trying to create a string that's composed with multiple parts. It starts as a normal string and at some point a function is called that fills a pointer with an hex number. Like shown below.

```
PVOID hexval = NULL;
PCTSTR mystring = TEXT("BLA");

function(&hexval);

mystring += hexval;  // just an idea of what I want, not actual code
```

As shown above I want `mystring` to have the `hexvalue` appended to it. Assume my `hexvalue` is `0x424C41`. I want to end with `mystring` being "BLABLA".

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What does the `TEXT()` macro do?

Comment: `mystring +=` is a bad sign if you are actually writing C code.

Comment: The most standard option is to use `sprintf`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @einpoklum It prepends a string literal with `L` when `UNICODE` is defined to make it a wide string (UTF-16)

Comment: @einpoklum The TEXT macro identifies a string as Unicode when UNICODE is defined by a preprocessor directive during compilation. Otherwise, the macro identifies a string as an ANSI string. @ David as I say in the comments that line is only to make clear what I would like to do.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: OP did say that was not real code.

Comment: @einpoklum Yes, but it's tagged "C" /;)

Comment: What type does `hexval` point to?

Comment: @Swordfish it's an ULONG_PTR

Comment: @einpoklum `TEXT` macro is [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(void)
{
    ULONG_PTR value  = 0x424C41;
    LPVOID hexval    = &value;
    PCTSTR mystring  = _T("BLA");

    size_t length    = _tcslen(mystring);
    size_t new_size  = length + sizeof(ULONG_PTR) + 1;

    LPTSTR new_string = calloc(new_size, sizeof(*new_string));
    _tcscpy(new_string, mystring);

    size_t offset;
    for (offset = sizeof(ULONG_PTR); offset && !((char*)hexval)[offset - 1]; --offset);

    for (size_t i = length ? length : 0, k = offset; k; ++i, --k)
        new_string[i] = ((char*)hexval)[k - 1];

    _tprintf(_T("\"%s\"\n"), new_string);
    free(new_string);
}
```

Maintaining ANSI-support in 2019 is masochism, though.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming I understand you correctly, and that UNICODE is not define by the preprocessor)

you should do the following:

1. Allocate space for a string which would contain both the original text and the new "text".
2. Copy the original string to the new location.
3. Concatenate the bytes of the hexval, from lowest to highest, after the copy of the original string.

There are two tricky points here:

1. You haven't explained how the "hex data" is terminated. Is there always a zero-valued byte at the "end" of it? Or - does it have a fixed size?
2. The order of bytes of the hex value may not be the order of bytes you want in a string. Some machines store the lowest byte first ("little-endian"; in your example, it would be 0x41, 0x4C, 0x42, 0x00 - assuming it's a 4-byte value) while others store the highest byte first ("big endian"). If you don't know you're on a little-endian machine, you'll need to reorder the bytes and you can't just copy from `hexval` directly.

**HOWEVER!** I advise you against doing any of this. It is much better to avoid getting into a situation in which you need to perform these brute-force conversions. I would bet you could probably solve whatever problem you're facing differently.

Comment: And is sprintf the best way to do it? The hex data has always the same fixed size.

Comment: @Diego: No, I didn't say `sprintf()` was the best way to do "it", because I don't know what "it" is. The three steps I suggested, on a little-endian machine would involve `malloc()` for allocation and `strcpy()` / `strncpy()` for copying the the two strings.